# Laravel: Session not changeable in Middleware?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have installed a fresh Laravel 5.5 application. I changed content of the `welcome.blade.php` to

```
{{ session('test') }}
```

and created a Middleware `SetSession.php` that I also included in the `Kernel.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetSession
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        session(['test' => 'A']);


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If I go to the browser I get the output

> A

If I now change the Middleware to

```
session(['test' => 'B']);
```

I still get the output

> A

and not `B`. I even changed the Middleware to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    session(['test' => 'B']);
    dd(\Session::all());


    return $next($request);
}
```

and the output was

> array:1 [▼   "test" => "B" ]

removing the `dd(..)` command results again in the output

> A

Why is the output B not showing?

I used the store method described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#storing-data). I could not find the command `\Session::all()` in the docs, but I found it on another post here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

As you are in a middleware, most of the helpers like session or auth are unavailable since they also rely on middlewares to work.

You should probably use the raw session from the request:

```
$request->session()->get('key');
$request->session()->set('key', 'value');
```

Comment: I just tried using your suggested `set` command or the `put` command from the docs, but it is not working. I get the error `Session store not set on request.`

Comment: Please check that your middleware is executed AFTER \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession middleware

Comment: Since its a fresh install, the `StartSession` middleware is at `$middlewareGroups`. Should I switch it to the `$middleware` array on top of my custom `SetSettion` middleware?

Comment: placing your SetSession inside $middleware doesn't make sense as StartSession is used only on the web group. Move the two together and in the correct order !

Comment: Sorry I am new to Laravel. What do you mean with "move the two together" ? How can I check that my middleware is executed after StartSession? Should I move `SetSession` to the `$middlewareGroups` array?

Comment: Yes as they don't make sense without each other, and SessionStart is meant to be in the web group